# Impossible to publish on Tomcat

Tags: windows, eclipse, tomcat8

At start I thought it was an Eclipse problem but continuing to make attempts I think the problem is upstream, in Tomcat indeed maybe in Windows even. Everything worked well until the last shutdown. Since I restarted the machine, trying to publishing on Tomcat I get errors like: "Could not replace with temp file ...", "Could not create directory ..." etc. Ultimately, the publication fails because I can no longer write to Tomcat's "webapps" folder. Actually I noticed that the whole "Program files" folder has become "read only". I tried to modify the attributes in all the ways, through changes to the properties of Windows (even giving "full controll" in "security" in the "Apache ... Tomcat" folder), through modifications of "attrib" using "PowerShell"... nothing to do: either the changes are not taken into consideration or I receive the message "access denied" (but I am system administrator).
I'm at my wit's end!
Ps _ Tomcat 8, win 10. No change was made to Tomcat or eclipse installation, no windows update in the last shutdown-restart.

Comment: Have you thought about re-installing your tomcat directory outside of the Program files? eg: C://tools/tomcat. You'll also have to reset the target of Tomcat in Eclipse.

Comment: this could be another of the countless attempts ... but I would also like to understand what the hell could have happened  to prevent this from happening again! How is it possible, only by switching the machine off and on again?

Comment: besides, mine is just a hypothesis. I am not sure that the problem is this as well because (but I have not yet verified well) if it were so, I would have to start to have problems on all the other programs that need accesses in writing too!